# Xamarin - This API is not supported on this version of iOS - UIKit.UIMenuElement

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a pretty basic master / detail Xamarin forms application that runs fine on recent iOS and Android devices.  When trying to deploy to a 32-bit iOS 9.3.5, we get the following error:  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invoication.  --> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This API is not supported on this version of iOS at UIKit.UIMenuElement..ctor.
[image: Error information]

The offending C# in our AppDelegate is:

```
 return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
```

I tried changing my iOS Supported Architecture to ARMv7 + ARMv7s + ARM64, but it still crashes.

I have updated our deployment mac to Xcode 11.1 and I am running VS 2019 with all updates and with the latest version of Xamarin.

Will I not be able to support iOS 9.x releases?

Comment: UIMenuElement is only available on iOS 13+. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenuelement You will need to check for current os version for iOS 13+ if on a lower OS then you will need to fallback to a different UI.

Comment: I did a search of the entire solution and there aren't any uses of UIMenuElement.  Does running the latest version of Xamarin prevent the deployment onto older devices?  We are only using simple controls like grids, contentpages, labels, etc.

Comment: That is strange, you should be able to deploy and run without any issues. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7084 looks like there was an issue open about this a few days ago. Last person to comment says hot reload might be the cause.

Comment: Lower the version of Xamarin Forms one by one until it works

Comment: @Saamer  Tried that going all the way back and still the same error.  My hunch is that it has to do with the mac build computer being on the latest version of XCode and having no other version to compile against.

Comment: Using VS, I’m able to support 9.x releases on my computer but I don’t use a windows. Have you tried using visual studio on your Mac directly?

Comment: @Saamer No, we only build on windows machines and use the mac as a build host.  We only have XCode 11.1 installed on the machine, When I look at SDK version in the Code Generation & Runtime properties in VS, I only get Default and 13.1.  My assumption is that I need multiple versions of XCode installed on the Mac and then target an SDK version that is compatible with iOS 9.